# Is there any way to store the emitted data once the emitted data is fetched?

Tags: vue.js

I am using EventBus. My code is below.

**app.js**

```
window.EventBus = new Vue();
```

**Below is the code that Emit**

```
EventBus.$emit('emitted', {
    SomeProperty: SomeData,
});
```

**Below is the code to retrieve the emitted data**

```
EventBus.$on('emitted', id => {

});
```

Is there any way to store the emitted data once the emitted data is fetched? I am trying to search if there is any way to save the emitted data somewhere?

Comment: Inside your receiving function this.someProp = id.SomeProperty. This would then store the data on the receiving component. Otherwhise could you specifiy where exactly you want to store the data?

Comment: Can I use the same property in an another component? I want to initialise a property in component 1 which is present in component 2

Comment: That's where you need shared state management. You should have a look into https://github.com/vuejs/vuex , which is the standard for vue state management. The good thing is that properties in this state are computed, which means you don't need to use events. Changing them anywhere updates them everywhere.

Comment: The state management is done purely in the browser and has therefore nothing to do with the backend (in your case laravel).
The topic itself is a little more complex, so I suggest you read through the documentation

Comment: Do you have any code example of how to use it in Laravel 5.5 and Vue.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Vue with Laravel:

```js
    // Your event bus
    const EventBus = new Vue()

    // The main Vue instance for your app
    const app = new Vue({
        // ALL YOUR APP LOGIC GOES HERE...

      methods: {
        fetchData (params) {
          // this is the method you use to fetch data, here you can use a library
          // like axios to query your api and return the result
                return axios.get('/api/someData', { params })
        }
      },
      // Every time your app is loaded, it executes the created() hook to retrieve
      // previously stored data from localStorage.
      // Depending on your needs, you can use mounted() hook instead.
      created () {
        // Attach the listener to store someData in localStorage
        EventBus.$on('someData', data => window.localStorage.setItem('someData', data))

        // check for stored someData
        const someData = window.localStorage.getItem('someData')

        if (someData) {
            // do something with someData
        }
        else {
            // there is no someData stored, so fetch and store ($emit)
            this.fetchData()
            .then(response => {
              if (response.data.someData) {
                EventBus.$emit('someData', response.data.someData)
              }
            })
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: Will u like to suggest something in this bounty question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868541/is-there-any-callback-for-on-leave-on-join-on-typing-in-vue-js

Comment: here is another bounty question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868541/is-there-any-callback-for-on-leave-on-join-on-typing-in-vue-js

Answer (score 4):

To save data and share between components, use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html)

To save data in [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), for convenience you can use [vue-ls](https://github.com/RobinCK/vue-ls)

Comment: A technical solution would be helpful, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

So far, I found below approach.

**To get saved data.**

```
localStorage.getItem("Key")
```

**To save data**

```
localStorage.setItem("Key")
```