# Is there any callback for on leave, on join , on typing in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5

**About**

I am learning Vue.js with Laravel. Presently, practicing on sending real time text messages between 2 users.

**Below code sends message to another user**

```
var url = "http://localhost:6001/apps/My_appId/events?auth_key=My_Key";

var socketId = Echo.socketId();
var request = {
    "channel": "private-Send-Message-Channel.2",
    "name": "MessengerEvent",
    "data": {
        "msg": message
    },
    "socket_id": socketId
};
axios.post(url, 
    JSON.stringify(request))
        .then((response) => {
        //Success callback
    }
);
```

**Receive the message**

```
window.Echo.private('Send-Message-Channel.2')   
    .on('MessengerEvent', (e) => {
      //Receive the message
    }
);
```

> Question: Is there any callback for on leave, on join , on typing, total users?

Comment: Perhaps this can help you out: https://laravel.com/docs/master/broadcasting#presence-channels

Comment: I am using vue.js (client side socket.io) unlike pusher

Comment: It does not matter, you are still using the echo server. You are just using a different broadcaster, this does not change the API.

Comment: in that case, can u correct my code with the needed callbacks?

Answer (score 1):

You need to user a `presence` channel. As described these channels are also private:

> All presence channels are also private channels

You can set up a presence channel by using `.join`.

```
Echo.join(`chat.${roomId}`)
    .here((users) => {
        //
    })
    .joining((user) => {
        console.log(user.name);
    })
    .leaving((user) => {
        console.log(user.name);
    });
```

There you have access to the callback that you are looking for.

Comment: This is I think not useful at all because I am using Client side Socket.io node.js

Comment: You are using socket.io as your broadcaster. That is something entirely different.

Comment: I mentioned it in my question. Unfortunately this is not an answer.